# Attribute width and height not allowed on element symbol at this point

Tags: html, svg, w3c, w3c-validation

Should `width` and `height` attribute not be used on SVG's `symbol`?

These are being used in MDN example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol

How to solve this validation error?

[image]

Comment: ignore it, it's not valid. If you're using the w3c validator it's been unmaintained for years AFAIK.

Comment: @RobertLongson It is being maintained it seems https://github.com/validator/validator

Comment: That's not the w3c validator. Anyway now that you've found the code, why not fork it and contribute a fix.

Comment: @RobertLongson post your comment as an answer, as it does answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just linking back the the GitHub issue https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/930 and response for anyone that comes across this:

> SVG 1.1 https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SymbolElement didn’t
>   allow width and height for the symbol element. But apparently the SVG2
>   spec does https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#SymbolElement.
>
> So I’ll update the checker to allow those.

Till it is fixed, you can ignore it from the commandline directly with a regex or a series of reges with the filterfile paramater https://github.com/validator/validator#--filterfile-filename